# HTML. Assign multiple classes with subclasses to a element

Tags: html, css, class, css-specificity

I'm struggling with HTML classes. I've got these classes in CSS:

```
.a{}
.a .b{}
.a .c{}
```

And I'm trying to assign two classes to elements like this:

```
<div class="a b"></div>
<div class="a c"></div>
```

But none of these work, the element only inherits "a" class. I think It is logically that the second class must be assigned in absolute way like:

```
<div class="a (a b)"></div>
```

But I can't find the correct way. Maybe what I'm trying to do is stupid but I can't find another way (keeping specificity in CSS).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The selector for "has both classes `a` and `b`" is `.a.b`, so no space in between.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to use this css on a markup

```
.a{}
.a .b{}
.a .c{}
```

Change

```
<div class="a b"></div>
<div class="a c"></div>
```

to

```
<div class="a">
   <div class="b"></div>
</div>
<div class="a">
   <div class="c"></div>
</div>
```

**Note:** *the space in css between to selectors mean [`Descendant selector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_selectors)*

the same way you have `>` alias [Child selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors) to selector the direct child ie:

```
.a{}
.a > .b{}
.a > .c{}
```

Now let us say you want to apply it to a single element, all what you have to do is to remove the space between those selectors like this:

```
.a{}
.a.b{}
.a.c{}
```

this style will the match this markup

```
<div class="a b"></div>
<div class="a c"></div>
```

Comment: Can find a way to do that with one single Div? Thanks.